# excel vba writing dates dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am creating a report page for my excel template and I want to add a "date" section below.

I simply wrote the code as this;

```
Worksheets("Report_TEMP").Range("H46:J46") = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

I don't know why, but the report gives me the date as "mm-dd-yyyy".
It show today as 10.12.2017 like US system.

How can I make it sure to write it as 12.10.2017 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply the formatting to the cells:

```
With Worksheets("Report_TEMP").Range("H46:J46")
   .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
   .Value = Date
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format as `DD.MM.YYYY` as mentioned below

```
Worksheets("Report_TEMP").Range("H46:J46") = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

It will give us the desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### you can use as a string, like this :

```
Worksheets("Report_TEMP").Range("H46:J46") = Cstr(Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"))
```